# Is a custom-made grate on an exhaust pipe a bad idea?

Tags: exhaust

To prevent would-be vandals from putting rocks or something in my tailpipe, can you foresee any long term effects from having custom-made grates on my exhaust pipes?

Comment: Have you had this happen to you? :/

Comment: No, but people just key nice vehicles for no reason at all. Watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2aC_oseMe4), which made my mind wonder back to a scene from show where the lead character stuck some rocks in the tailpipe of the guy that she liked, but she later removed them. :-)

Comment: They are more likely to steal your vehicle than vandalize it.

Comment: Buy custom tail pipes with a mesh on it. Whatever makes you sleep at night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as long as the grate is not too fine a mesh, 1/8" or larger mesh is fine.